# How to start SQL Server 2017 on Linux in single user mode/ masteronly recovery mode?

Tags: sql-server-2017

How to start SQL Server 2017 on Linux in single user mode / masteronly recovery mode?

The scenario behind this question is we can move tempdb files to a new filesystem. What if I specify a wrong filesystem and restart SQL Server on linux. SQL Server will go down. In this case how to change tempdb location in system catalog?

Answer (score 1):

If SQL Server is running, stop SQL Server:

```
sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
```

Switch to the user `mssql`. No password is required.

```
sudo su mssql
```

Start the SQL Server binary in single-user mode:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr -m
```

Do whatever you need to do. When finished press CTRL-C

Start SQL Server:

```
sudo systemctl start mssql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the -m flag when starting the process will enable single user mode.