# Cannot connect to SQL Server - maximum number of '1' user connections has already been reached

Tags: sql-server, centos7

I can't connect to Microsoft SQL Server. It says:

> Logon       Could not connect because the maximum number of '1' user
> connections has already been reached. The system administrator can use
> sp_configure to increase the maximum value. The connection has been
> closed. [CLIENT: XXX.XXX.XX.XX]

It's on Centos 7. I tried connect by Management Studio, SQLCMD and restarting- nothing works. Every information I found in Google said that I need to increase limit of connections, but how can I do that without actual being connected to database?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; you're running the instance in single user mode and you already have a connection. Also, CentOS isn't a supported operating system, so you should really being running the instance on a OS that it supports.

Comment: So I need to change OS?

Comment: I wouldn't say "need" no; taking the instance out of single user mode would likely fix the problem, however, using a supported OS would be a good idea as well.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how can I change from single user mode to multi user mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start SQL Server 2017 on Linux in single user mode/ masteronly recovery mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005575/how-to-start-sql-server-2017-on-linux-in-single-user-mode-masteronly-recovery-m) Obviously you need to reverse that. It might be the DB which is in single user, so `ALTER DATABASE myDB SET MULTI_USER;`

Comment: The error isn't a single user database, @Charlieface , you don't change the maximum number of connections a database can handle with `sp_configure`.